# Hot key/shortcut for point, edge and face select?

Tags: shortcut

Is there a default hotkey or shortcut for changing between point edge and face select in edit mode? It can be annoying to have to click the bottom every time. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>** to bring up the mesh select mode

[image]

Comment: **Does not seem to work with Blender 2.80**. Any idea if there's option to change this without mouse in latest version?

Comment: After searching for long enough I found it. With **Blender 2.80** you can toggle *Edit mode* with `Tab` and then activate *Vertex select* with `1`, *Edge select* with `2` and *Face select* with `3`. Note that the mouse cursor must be above the viewport for this to work!

Comment: See also: https://developer.blender.org/T55162